# Loop through all matching pattern, leaving the original string for the rest

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with a content like this:

```
bird://localhost:${xfire.port}/${plfservice.url}
${configtool.store.folder}/config/hpctemplates.htb
```

I'd like to run a script which resolves all variables to get their values. Let's call the script resolve.sh. I'd like to loop through all matching pattern, but want to get an output including the original file, where the variables are substituted by the resolved values. Example for output:

```
bird://localhost:8043/net-littlecat-rbp.jms
/cat/dog/installation/configtool/config/hpctemplates.htb
```

So, resolve.sh runs where it finds a string between ${ } and the rest of the file remains the original. How can I get this?

Comment: It's tempting to make a temporary `bash` script from the input file, putting an `echo` in front of each line, but with a line at the top with `source resolve.sh`

Comment: But the danger is that there might be special characters like `<`, `>`,`;` in the file that should be escaped at the same time the `echo` is prefixed.  Which will then get into double and single quote issues, to escape inside them or not.  Ugh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file and replace it globally with ENV vars then output it to the file which includes the origin filename, right?

Here is resolve.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

PORT=1234 # xfire.port
URL=abc   # plfservice.url
DIR=xyz   # configtool.store.folder

# subsitude with ENV vars
C=$(sed -e "s/\${xfire.port}/${PORT}/g" \
        -e "s_\${plfservice.url}_${URL}_g" \
        -e "s_\${configtool.store.folder}_${DIR}_g"< $1)

# original filename
F="original filename: ${1%}"

# output to file which specified by $2
cat >$2 <<END
${C}
${F}
END
```

Call resolve.sh: `./resolve.sh <your-input-file> <your-output-file>`

Comment: I guess this would be a great solution. Unfortunately I get "ambiguous redirect" for the two lines which contain redirection:

-e "s/\${configtool.store.folder}/${DIR}/g"< $1)
and 
cat >$2 <<END

Isn't there something wrong with the format?

Comment: No, sorry, it was my fault. Just too many tries and getting confused... :-) It seems to be working! Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more question:
When the variable value contains a "/", like 
DIR=xyz/uhk
sed substitution doesn't work correctly, maybe because it understands the / character differently. When I remove the / from the value, the script works perfectly. What can I do for sed to handle the / character correctly in the variable value?

Comment: @azilinha You can replace 's/<pattern>/<replacement>/g' with 's_<pattern>_<replacement>_g' for directories substitution. I'd adjust the code and you can try it later.

Comment: Thanks a lot, perfect!

Comment: You're helping a lot but one more question, please. :-) If I have a separated file with the patterns and replacement, how can I read them into the sed command?

Comment: E.g. cat file 
PORT=1234
URL=abc
DIR=xyz/uhk
In the script sed should use always the value of the first column of the file as pattern and the second one as replacement. It's because my file has too many lines to insert each one manually into resolve.sh. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to figure how to do it `awk` nor `sed`. But in Perl it works like a charm:

```
perl -ape 's/\${([^}]*)}/$ENV{$1}/g'
```